# Why is flask using all of my memory?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I created the simplest Flask app I could imagine:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.jsonify(ok=True)
```

I deployed this app on 1/26 to Elastic Beanstalk.  It has served 0 requests since deployment.  Here is a graph of the memory usage, using [Amazon's memory monitoring scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html):

[image: Flask, why you no free?]

You can see the little dip where (I assume) garbage collection happened on 1/29. But what on earth is allocating so much memory?  If this is normal, how should I be monitoring memory so I can actually figure out if my (real) application has a memory leak?  Is this Flask's fault, Python's fault, AWS's fault, ...something else?

*Edited to add:* I switched over to using mod_wsgi this aftenoon, but it didn't seem to have any effect.  Updated graph (the dips are deploying new versions, it took a few tries to get the config right):

[image: Continuing memory issues with WSGI]

Output of `free -m`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           532        501         31          0         81         37
-/+ buffers/cache:        381        150
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that memory actually being used or is it cached? SSH into your beanstalk instance and use the `free` command to determine this. [This article](https://www.linuxatemyram.com/) has a good breakdown of how to determine whether your RAM is actually used or cached and what it means.

Comment: Unfortunately, `free` on Elastic Beanstalk doesn't have the `available` column! (I'd guess it's too old?)  However, it sounds like the `buffers/cache` line's `free` column is a reasonable proxy for that, and that's holding steady at ~145MB.

Comment: I added the output of `free` to the bottom my question.

Comment: Cool, so yes, the line that says `-/+ buffers/cache` shows the actual memory being used. The rest is being held in cache and will be released by the OS as required for other programs.