# Docker container memory usage not going down

Tags: docker, memory-management, docker-compose, containers

I have a flask web server running with docker-compose. 
When the container first starts, it starts by using around **200MB** of memory but after some use goes up to **1GB** (docker stats). 
However once it reaches high consumption, even when idle, the memory usage of the container is not decreasing and eventually hitting the limit - causing dead uwsgi workers and stopped processes.
Can someone explain what happens behind the curtain and how to have the container release unused memory?

Comment: Maybe here you will find the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506113/why-is-flask-using-all-of-my-memory

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this a bug and it is being tracked 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70179